# How to use SDWebImage Frame work in UICollectionview for image parsing from web services?

Tags: ios, sdwebimage

i am new in iOS development.i want to know how to use SDWebImage Framework for image Parsing through web services and put images on the collection-view custom cell?Any resource for that then please give me.

Answer (score 1):

I would urge you to use DLImageLoader.  It is incredibly well maintained, and basically critical in iOS.

**Nowadays DLImageLoader has a perfect Swift version, too.**

https://github.com/AndreyLunevich/DLImageLoader-iOS/tree/master/DLImageLoader

It's this easy to load an image properly...

```
-(UICollectionViewCell *)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)cv
         cellForItemAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
    {
    NSInteger thisRow = indexPath.row;
    BooksCell *cell;
    cell = [cv dequeueReusableCellWithReuseIdentifier:
              @"CellBooksNormal" forIndexPath:indexPath];

    cell.layer.shouldRasterize = YES;
    cell.layer.rasterizationScale = [UIScreen mainScreen].scale;

    // set text items...
    cell.title = @"blah";

    // set image items using DLImageLoader

    __weak UIBookView *loadMe = cell.anImage;
    [DLImageLoader loadImageFromURL:imUrl
       completed:^(NSError *error, NSData *imgData)
        {
        [loadMe use:[UIImage imageWithData:imgData]];
        }];

    return cell;
    }
```

When you say web services, here's how to get the facebook user avatar for instance

```
PFObject *aFacebookUser = [self.fbFriends objectAtIndex:thisRow];
NSString *facebookImageURL = [NSString stringWithFormat:
    @"http://graph.facebook.com/%@/picture?type=large",
    [aFacebookUser objectForKey:@"id"] ];

__weak UIImageView *loadMe = self.cellImage;
[DLImageLoader loadImageFromURL:facebookImageURL
   completed:^(NSError *error, NSData *imgData)
    {
    if ( loadMe == nil ) return;

    if (error == nil)
        {
        UIImage *image = [UIImage imageWithData:imgData];
        image = [image ourImageScaler];
        loadMe.image = image;
        }
    else
        {
        // an error when loading the image from the net
        }
    }];
```

Comment: The original question was about SDImageCache. Why is DLImageLoader better besides its activity... is it the API, how it caches, etc?